# How do i use the extraParams in Jquery Autocomplete?

Tags: django, autocomplete

Am using Django and i want to access extraParams data of Jquery Autocomplete.

my Autocomplete code looks like this .

```
$("#power-search").autocomplete("/power_search_lookup/",{
type:"post",
extraParams:{model_name:function(){ return PMS.power_search_model_name;}},
width:320,
muliple:false,
multipleSeparator:",",
scroll:true,
scrollHeight:300,
delay:10,
formatResult:format_power_search
});
```

From django how do i get to read **model_name**

Gath

Answer (score 0):

Its working ...

This Parameter was empty when i was sending it to the server! when it has a value it works well.

```
PMS.power_search_model_name;
```

Thanks.